# Can I install Adobe CS4 alongside CS6 via Creative Cloud?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, cs4

I'm using MacOS Sierra and I currently have CS6 installed, via Creative Cloud.

However, my current client is using some proprietary content management software which only integrates with CS4.

Is it possible to install CS4 alongside CS6, via Creative Cloud? Specifically, I need InDesign CS4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run fusion on the mac, which will support older versions of Mac OSX. Easier to setup than dual boot. I believe they have a 30 day trial, so you can test before you buy.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple versions (CS4, CS5, CS6, CC) of the same software installed on your computer at the same time.

You cannot install CS4 from the Creative Cloud app. You can download CS6 and below programs from the Adobe website but you will need a serial code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "You can download CS6..." - I presume you mean "You can download CS4..."?

Comment: @VanjaPakaski I mean you can download CS6 and below including CS4.

Comment: For CS6 you actually do *not* need a dedicated serial code. If you are subscribed to the Creative Cloud you can download CS6 from their site and install it on your system.

Answer (score 3):

While you *can* have multiple instances of the Adobe applications installed and Andrew is *100% correct* in his answer.

**Adobe Creative Suite 4 will not run on MacOS Sierra (10.12).** The operating system is newer and CS4 is too old. In fact, CS4 support stopped with MacOS 10.8 (Mountain Lion) - maybe it was 10.7. I can't remember specifically, but you can't run CS4 on Apple's latest operating systems.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a great help. Saves me from chasing a dead end! Now to work out what I should do to get CS4 running *somewhere*...

Comment: Install Snow Leopard 10.6.8, if possible, and dual boot the system. Nightmarish.. but saves costs on old hardware. Of course, chances are if the Mac shipped with anything newer than 10.6... it won't run Snow Leopard either.